# How to use V-For after an axios request retrieves data?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuetify.js

How do i populate `V-Cards` dynamically after the `Axios` request has retrieved Data?

The `axios` request completes correctly but `v-for` never populates with `v-cards`.  I have also tried making the request before render is complete (beforeCreate lifecycle event) this fails also.

Edit: Data retrieval completes successfully which is what makes me think its an issue with how v-for is working? maybe I am missing something?
https://i.stack.imgur.com/HVBc7.jpg (response data)

```js
<template>
  <v-container class="pa-2" fluid>
      <v-layout v-for="(clip) in clipData" :key="clip.id">
        <v-card>
          <v-img
            :src="clip.thumbnail_url"
            class="white--text"
            height="200px"
          >
            <v-card-title class="fill-height align-end" v-text="clip.title"></v-card-title>
          </v-img>
        </v-card>
      </v-layout>
  </v-container>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
// Imports omitted for brevity


@Component({
  components: {}
})
export default class Clips extends Vue {

  public clipData: any;

  mounted() {
    // Axios Request Data From twitch helix API regarding Clip Information on My channel
    helix.get('clips?broadcaster_id=<myidOmitted>&first=10').then((data) => {
        this.clipData = data.data.data; // <-- Third data is the array of clips i need.
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.log(err)
    })
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: my apologies helix.get is the Axios call,  Helix is axios.create with a base URL,  Please see mounted() lifecycle event  - Updated question with better comments in snippet

Comment: What happens if you print out `this.clipData` after the assignment in the callback of your axios request? Is it `undefined`?

Comment: not    undefined   but an Empty array,  which is strange as debugging via chrome displays an array of 10 Clip Objects being returned correctly

Comment: Are you sure, that you are accessing it correctly? `data.data.data`?

Comment: maybe the data are in another property

Comment: bad naming strategy - first data is "response" from axios,  second data is Axios Response.data, third data is Array of Clip Objects within the response data

Comment: Is the data correct in the DevTools/Network tab after the ajax request? An empty array indicates that you might passed a wrong request param to the API which then returned an empty array.

Comment: the data coming back after the request is indeed correct - https://imgur.com/a/uOqZ2wN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so nothing here worked so I got to thinking what if the UI was not being updated after data had retrieved properly,

So in my Parent Container i placed a Property in v-if

```
<v-container class="ma-10" v-if="!isFetching" >
```

and when the Axios call was finished, i updated this property to be false

```
helix.get('clips?broadcaster_id=<idOmitted>&first=8').then((data) => {
    this.clipData = data.data.data; // <-- Third data is the array of clips i need.
    this.isFetching = false;
```

This solved it immediately,  I guess when setting a variable it triggered a re-render of the UI?  I am unsure why this worked as we where already setting a Variable (clipData).

However Issue Solved for now!

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using "ts", we can write it like this too(make the mounted hook as a async and just use the await for axios call)

```
async mounted() {  

  let response = await helix.get('clips?broadcaster_id=<myidOmitted>&first=10');
  if(response.data){
    this.clipData = response.data.data;
   }  
 }
```

hope this will work for you.